# Access properties from source folder for exporting to runnable jar

Tags: java, properties

I need to access the properties file from my jar when i export to runnable jar.So when i put props file in project root folder in eclipse it is running.But when exported it is not copied.So i wanted it to placed within source folder. So how to access it from source folder.

java.io.FileNotFoundException: config.properties (The system cannot find the fil
e specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:106)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:66)
    at com.my.ashwinsakthi.twitterclient.IplHashtagReader.main(IplHashtagReader.jav
a:38)[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied the properties file into the jar and placed where my java class files where there and it worked...

Answer (score 0):

1,is the properties file packed in the jar file?

2,use `MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties")` instead.

`new File(filename)` will searching filename in user.dir

Comment: no it is not getting packed when i put it in the root --MyTwitterApplication folder.But the program runs in eclipse when i put it there.

Comment: It's in source folder src,It will be copied to WebContent/WEB-INF/classes/ folder,so eclipse can find it.but in runnable jar,JVM can't find it